# no entries in itemize section

Tags: itemize

I get a message of the following type in log file, https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/LaTeX_Error:_Something%27s_wrong--perhaps_a_missing_%5Citem
There are no entries found in the list at line 23

```
\begin{itemize}
     \textendash\textbf{i} To be able to understand the anomaly detection techniques by existing service providers.
     \textendash\textbf{ii} To be able to implement an approach which can detect anomalies in a given data set.\\
\end{itemize}
```

I want to know what is wrong in above usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is clear: there is no `\item`, so you could add one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
     \item[\textendash\textbf{i}] To be able to understand the anomaly detection techniques by existing service providers.
     \item[\textendash\textbf{ii}] To be able to implement an approach which can detect anomalies in a given data set.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Of course, there are much better ways to get the same result, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textendash\textbf{\roman*}, ref=\textbf{\arabic*}]
     \item To be able to understand the anomaly detection techniques by existing service providers.
     \item To be able to implement an approach which can detect anomalies in a given data set.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also removed a `\\` which should not be there (and caused an `underfull hbox` message.

Comment: what does label tag do I have seen it used at many places

Comment: @koeradoera In this context it formats the labels of the items. In enumerate there is a counter and `label=\textendash\textbf{\roman*}` says that is should first add a `\textendash` and then a boldface version of the lowercase Roman representation of that counter.

Comment: @koeradoera note that the `label=` used here is the visible item label, and not related to the standard latex command `\label` which is for cross references